# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{2 \pi} {\cos^2 \theta \over a + b \cos \theta}\; d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Given $a > b > 0$ what is the fastest possible way to evaluate the following integral using Residue theorem. I'm confused weather to take the imaginary part of $z^2$ or whole integral.
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} {\cos^2 \theta \over a + b \cos \theta}\; d\theta$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $z=e^{i\theta}$, then $\cos\theta=\dfrac 1 2\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)$, and $dz=ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta/2=iz\,d\theta/2$, so $-2i\dfrac{dz}{z} = d\theta$.  Then
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2\theta}{a+b\cos\theta} d\theta = \int\limits_\text{circle} \frac{\frac14\left(z+\frac1z\right)^2}{a+\frac b2\left(z+\frac1z\right)}(-i)\frac{dz}{z} = -i\int\limits_\text{circle} \frac{z^4+2z^2+1}{2z^2(2az+b(z^2+1))} dz.
$$

This function has a double pole at $z=0$ and simple poles at $\dfrac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$.  So the question is: for which values of $a,b$ are the simple poles inside the circle?  If there's just one simple pole inside the circle at $c$, then the integral becomes
$$
\int\limits_\text{circle} \frac{g(z)}{z-c} dz = 2\pi i g(c),
$$
where $g(z)$ is whatever's left after you've factored out $1/(z-c)$.  If there's more than one simple pole, you need a sum: take values of $g$ at those points and sum them.

Comment: Actually I found I could substitute $ \cos^2 \theta = Im(z^2)$ and simplify things a lot :D
the whole integral will be $ Im ( \int z^2/...)$

Comment: We have $e^{2i\theta}=\cos[2\theta]+i\sin[2\theta]$. You take the real part ($\cos^{2}[\theta]-\sin^{2}[\theta]$), not the imaginary part (which is $2\sin[\theta]\cos[\theta]$ instead).

Comment: @Michael: We have $\cos[\theta]=\frac{1}{2}(\cos[\theta]+i\sin[\theta])+(\cos[\theta]-i\sin[\theta])$, you missed a factor.

Comment: @user32240 : Fixed now, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

We should have

$$\frac{\cos^{2}\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}=\frac{1}{b}\cos\theta-\frac{\frac{a}{b}\cos\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}.$$

The first part of the definite integral is easily evaluated. The second part is the same as evaluating

$$\int \frac{\cos\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}d\theta=\int\frac{1}{b}\left(1-\frac{a}{a+b\cos\theta}\right)d\theta.$$

So we only need to evaluate

$$\int\frac{1}{a+b\cos\theta}d\theta.$$

This can be done by various trignometry identities such as using $\tan(\theta/2)$. A detailed step by step proof can be found [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201/%28a%2bb%5Ccos%5Btheta%5D%29d%5Ctheta) (click show steps).

Comment: thanks for idea ... I think i can evaluate $\frac{1}{a+b\cos[\theta]}d\theta$ very easily

Comment: well, I am not sure if this is the "fastest possible" way to do it. I guess you are expecting some contour integral or manipulations involving $\Gamma$ functions.

Comment: I'm supposed to use contour integral ... the $z^2$ part is awful

Answer (score 2):

Hint: put $z={\rm e}^{i\theta}$ and change the integral to the form $ \int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz \,,$ then use residue theorem. Exploit the identity 
$$ \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}\left({\rm e}^{i \theta} + {\rm e}^{- i \theta}\right)\,. $$

Comment: Are you suggesting doing an integral of the form $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{2}}{a+bz}$? But though it has an obvious pole at $z=-\frac{a}{b}$(which is outside of the contour), I do not see how to get the original integral from $\cos[\theta]=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: yeah ... kinda something like that. But instead of squaring ... you can take Real part of $z^2$ which makes the problem very simple. Kinda confused on that

Comment: I am not sure how to deal with the bottom part, $(a+b\cos[\theta])$ is not easily treatable.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over a + b\cos\pars{\theta}}\,
     \dd\theta:\ {\large ?}.\qquad\qquad a > b > 0}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over a + b\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
> =2\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over a - b\cos\pars{\theta}}\,
> \dd\theta
> =-\,{2 \over b}
> \int_{0}^{\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over \cos\pars{\theta} - \mu}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{where}\quad\mu \equiv {a \over b}\,,\qquad  \mu > 1
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over a + b\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
=-\,{2 \over b}\int_{0}^{\pi}{%
\bracks{\cos\pars{\theta} - \mu}\bracks{\cos\pars{\theta} + \mu}  + \mu^{2}
\over \cos\pars{\theta} - \mu}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=-\,{2 \over b}\int_{0}^{\pi}\bracks{\cos\pars{\theta} + \mu}\,\dd\theta
-{2 \over b}\,\mu^{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over \cos\pars{\theta} - \mu}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over a + b\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
> =-\,{2a \over b^{2}}\,\pi - {2a^{2} \over b^{3}}
> \color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over \cos\pars{\theta} - \mu}}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

With the usual
[Weierstrass Tangent Half-Angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution):
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over \cos\pars{\theta} - \mu}}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}{2\,\dd t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}\over
\pars{1 - t^{2}}/\pars{1 + t^{2}} - \mu}
=-2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{\mu + 1}t^{2} + \mu - 1}
\\[3mm]&=-2\,{1 \over \mu - 1}\,\root{\mu - 1 \over \mu + 1}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}}^{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 2}}}
=-\,{\pi \over \root{\mu^{2} - 1}}\ =\
=-\,{b \over \root{a^{2} - b^{2}}}\,\pi
\end{align}

> Replacing in $\pars{1}$:
>   $$
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} \over a + b\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> ={2a \over b^{2}}\pars{{a \over \root{a^{2} - b^{2}}} - 1}\pi}\,,\qquad a > b > 0
> $$