# Parameterize the following about a unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How do I compute the following integral using contour integration:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2 \theta}{6-2\cos\theta}d\theta$$

Comment: Parametrize? The integral?...What's the question, anyway? What's your effort, what've you done so far?

Comment: I'm supposed to re-express as a paramaerization of a complex line integral of a unit circle.  I do not understand how to approach this problem.

Comment: Tom, is this $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{6-4\cos\theta}\,d\theta$?

Comment: @Tom: I edited you question the way I understood it. Feel free to change it. Also, you can learn a little about presenting your questions in $\LaTeX$ by looking at my edit.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189575/evaluate-the-integral-int-02-pi-cos2-theta-over-a-b-cos-theta/189581#189581).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Denote $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. Then, for $t\in[0,2\pi]$ $\gamma$ is the contour of the unit circle. Use the definition of contour integration in reverse:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos t,\sin t)dt=\int_\gamma f\left(\frac12(z+z^{-1}),\frac1{2i}(z-z^{-1})\right)\frac{dz}{iz}$$
Now use [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: $\sin t=\frac{1}{2i}(z-z^{-1})$.

Comment: Yeah, now corrected.