# Complex Variable Theory Integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Integrate $\int_0^ {2\pi} \frac{sin^2\theta} {2 - cos\theta} d\theta $

I used the substitutions sin($\theta$) = $\frac{ z - z^{-1}}{2i} $ 
and cos($\theta$) = $\frac{ z + z^{-1}}{2} $ and d$\theta$ = $\frac{1}{iz}dz$ transforming the integral into $\frac{-i}{2} \oint \frac{1}{z^2}\frac{(z-1)^2}{z^2-4z+1}dz$ leaving me at the point where I am stuck.

Comment: Very unclear what the function is you're integrating. Also, what have you tried.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189575/evaluate-the-integral-int-02-pi-cos2-theta-over-a-b-cos-theta/189581#189581).

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?  Can you find the poles inside the unit circle and the residues there?

Answer (score 0):

The function has period $2\pi$, so $I=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2x\, dx}{2-\cos x}=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2x\, dx}{2-\cos x}$,

also it is even function, so $I=2\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2x\, dx}{2-\cos x}$. Now take $t=\tan\frac{x}2$